# Not clear code procedure in Arduino wire library

Tags: c++, i2c, c, wire-library

The application code of sparkFun, has the following line which is difficult to understand.

It's requested 6, because it's requesting 6 bytes for HMC5883L module.

```
Wire.requestFrom(address, 6);
if(6<=Wire.available())
```

Where:

```
int TwoWire::available(void)
{
  return rxBufferLength - rxBufferIndex;
}
```

So, the available function should return `return rxBufferLength - rxBufferIndex;` where `rxBufferIndex` is modified in `read` function:

```
int TwoWire::read(void)
{
  int value = -1;

  // get each successive byte on each call
  if(rxBufferIndex < rxBufferLength){
    value = rxBuffer[rxBufferIndex];
    ++rxBufferIndex;
  }

  return value;
}
```

But, my current question is why decrementing `return rxBufferLength - rxBufferIndex;` where `rxBufferIndex` is initialized to 0 all the time, and there's no chance the returned value would be less than 6, because that would terminate the if statement?

Comment: What is the rxBufferLength value in your example?

Comment: 6 according to HMC5883L 6 bytes data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rxBufferLength` is the number of bytes that have been received. `rxBufferIndex` is the byte you would next be handed with a `read()` function call.

So if you have received 6 bytes from the slave (which you will, since that is how many you requested) but not read any the `available` would be 6. Ergo, 6 <= 6. I.e., you asked for 6, it collected 6, and you are checking that it got at least 6 (it can never be >6 since you only asked for 6, so why they look for at least 6 I don't know).

`rxBufferIndex` is never decremented. It is incremented when you read a byte, up until `rxBufferLength == rxBufferIndex` at which point there is 0 bytes available.

---

> But, my current question is why decrementing return rxBufferLength - rxBufferIndex; where  rxBufferIndex is initialized to 0 all the time, and there's no chance the returned value would be less than 6, because that would terminate the if statement?

The way that Wire.h works is that `available()` will always return the number of bytes you requested if the call to `requestFrom()` succeeded until you first read some of that data. If you request 6 and the call worked then you have 6. The `if` could just as well be written as:

```
if (Wire.available()) {...
```

since it will always be 6 immediately after a successful call. However, that makes assumptions about how the Wire API works and could be subject to change in the future or operate differently on different platforms.

So it checks that, right after the call to `requestFrom()` for 6 bytes it actually got *at least* 6 bytes. Without seeing what is inside the conditional `if`, all I can do is make assumptions, but I would assume that it is then reading those 6 bytes, and so it wouldn't care if there happened to be more for some reason. But it doesn't want there to be 5 or fewer bytes available when it is reading 6 of them.

An `if` statement doesn't "terminate" if its condition becomes false once it has been executed. It's not like a `while` that keeps running until it's false - it's a single decision made at a single point in time. If anything changes in the future that would have caused a difference decision to be made (e.g., you `read()` a byte, so `available()` would now return 5), the decision that has been made still stands.

An analogy for you:

You want to go out for a good healthy walk - but only if it's not raining.

```
if (!raining) {
    walk_to_shop();
    walk_to_cafe();
    drink_coffee();
    walk_to_shop();
    walk_home();
}
```

You go out for your walk to the shops, get a coffee, do some more shopping, and then walk home - but you only *start* doing that if it's not raining. If it starts raining while you're out you don't suddenly teleport back home.  You *could* make the decision, when you come out of the cafe and see it's raining, to cut your shopping trip short, but you have to actively make that decision. Just because `raining` becomes true doesn't affect the fact that you are outside and walking.

Comment: I edited the  question.

Comment: I think you're getting confused about what n `if` is.

Comment: What confused me is `if(6<=Wire.available())` because `available` returns `rxBufferLength - rxBufferIndex;` so if `rxBufferLength` is 6 and  `rxBufferIndex` is 0, then `available` returns 6, which is `true` in this case. But, if `rxBufferIndex` is 1 or 2, then `available` returns 5 or 4, which is `false`. So, how's that `if` statement is working? Does `if(6<=Wire.available())` returns the value one time, or it returns with all `rxBufferIndex` increments inside wire library?

Comment: @PerchEagle At the moment the `if()` executes `Wire.available()` will equal 6. That is the only time the `if()` executes, and it can only ever give 6, since nothing has been read at that point.

Comment: OK, I understand now, it runs only one time and the function every time returns 6. Thank you :) but I have another problem, the good news I succeeded accomplishing my I2C code, and that was amazing, but I have a new problem passing an array to `I2C_tx` function, I don't know why it's not working. I should ask about it in a new post.